# Login menu not appearing when created using meteor

Tags: user-interface, authentication, meteor, meteorite

I am new to Meteor of course for developing filed as well. I have created a login UI using meteor, but it is not visible. I am able to see through inspect element using console. Can some one tell me what went wrong.

```
<body>
<div class="container">
   {{> header}}
   <div id="main" class="row-fluid">
        {{renderPage}}
    </div>
</div>           
</body>
<template name="header">
    <header class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="/">Jobboard</a>
            <ul class="nav">
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
                <li>{{loginButtons}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</template>
```

Comment: you have added accounts-base accounts-ui and accounts-password right? otherwise it may be a CSS issue so we may need to see more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your `<header>` tag. Use consistent indentation to make these issues more obvious:

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    {{> header}}
    <div id="main" class="row-fluid">
      {{renderPage}}
    </div>
  </div>           
</body>

<template name="header">
  <header class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <a class="brand" href="/">Jobboard</a>
      <ul class="nav">
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav pull-right">
        <li>{{loginButtons}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
</template>
```